# Python: requests module do not cache, why this error then?

Tags: caching, python-requests, windows-server-2008, python-3.5

I have a link to a raw txt file in github of the form https://raw.githubusercontent.com/XXX/YYY/master/txtfile where I want to periodically put a new version so a python script will know that it must update, the python script (py 3.5) uses an infinite while loop and the module [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/):

```
while True:

    try:
        r = requests.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/XXX/YYY/master/txtfile', timeout=10)
        required_version = r.text
    except:
        required_version = 0

    log_in_txt_file(required_version)

    sleep(10)
```

This script runs under Windows, however, I remark that despite the version is updated on the server, the log still show that the request is getting the previous version! If I try to get the version from a browser (Chrome) the same happens, but after some F5 the new version appears (in the browser and in the log), however, the script still log sometimes the old, sometimes the new version! I tried to make the URL variable with:

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/XXX/YYY/master/txtfile?_=time.time
```

But the problem remain, I'm using an Amazon workspace and I'm pretty sure it's a OS issue, my question, how to workaround this using python? Any idea?

Comment: But Github caches on the server side..

Comment: even if I add a random parameter?!

Comment: Random parameters serve to break *client side* caches. Github doesn't care about a random parameter.

Comment: Why not test with another client, such as `curl` or `wget` or your browser and see if the data actually has changed? `requests` certainly doesn't cache anything client side.

Comment: but:
1. Why do I receive wobbling responses? at times the old data, at times the new one?!
2. Does Github also cache on the normal (non raw) page?

Comment: You are asking a CDN network for content. That network consists of multiple machines, they don't all update at the same time. So sometimes you get one machine serving new content, another time you get a machine serving old content.

Comment: Yes, I'd expect their regular pages to use caching too.

Comment: Great, so my script can work at some extent, this is sufficient for me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a client-side caching issue. In effect, Github *servers* are caching the version, serving you content until they are updated in time.

Github serves your data from a series of webservers, distributed geographically to ease loading times. These servers don't all update at the same time; until a change has propagated to all servers you'll see old and new content returned on that URL, depending on what machine served you the content for a specific request.

You can't really use GitHub to detect when a new version has been released, not reliably. Instead, generate a unique filename (generate a GUID perhaps) that *at a future time* will contain the new version information. Give that filename out with the current version, and try and poll that. Releasing a new version then consists of generating the filename for the version after, and putting the information to the current 'new version' URL. Each version links to the next file, and when it appears you only need to load it *once*.

Comment: This is a good idea, however, I prefered to use available services on the net such as Github, your solution rely on having authority on the "future version" URL to modify its content, I want to avoid this. There plenty of services (pastebin, ... etc) but no one gives the ability to modify content of links, do you know such a service?

Comment: I'm not aware of any services that guarantee atomic updates to a file, now and in the future. That's just not scalable.

Comment: despite of the caching problem, I think github is my best solution :)